# Chrome claims a function takes long but it is never called

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I'm wondering why Chrome tells me the following line of code aggregates to over 400ms (in a 9s audit) even though it is never called:

[image]

I never see the log in my console.
Does anyone have an idea why Chrome thinks this line is expensive?

Thanks,
Jesse

Comment: Without more details no.

Comment: Well. There's nothing really to go on here. I'm assuming that this is in some sort of a loop. So, check out the vastness of what you're iterating over.

Comment: Not really a loop but it's a component that's used quite often. 
Apparently the problem was using `innerHTML` a few lines later. Using `textContent` instead removed this aggregation of time. So I guess Chrome just marked the wrong line?

Thanks for your fast responses.